# The name fileitem does not exist in the current context Error

Tags: c#

When I run my application I get the following error.

> The name fileitem does not exist in the current context

```
public class foo
{
    string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    StreamReader fileitem;
    StreamReader fileuser;
    public foo()
    {
        fileitem = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(desktop, "one.txt"));
        fileuser = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(desktop, "two.txt"));
    }
}
```

---

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int x = 0; x <= 8939500; x++)
    {
        lineuser = fileuser.ReadLine();                //The error line
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineuser))
    {
            string[] values = lineuser.Split(' ');
            int userid, factoriduser;
            foreach (string value in values)
    {
........
```

Comment: your error and code doesn't match. Where have you defined `lineuser` in your code.

Comment: where have you defined `one`? Does file `one.txt` exists? Do you have permissions to access it?

Comment: at the begining of the code. before public class foo . string lineuser;

Comment: Sorry @Javad_Amiry. I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Create an Instance of `Class Foo` then call it's member `lineuser` on this instance like this one. You are trying to access a private field from `Class Foo` which is wrong. You can not read members of a class without instantiating them first. To access Private fields you need to declare properties. Below is the code how you can do this.

```
    public class foo
    {
        string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        StreamReader fileitem;
        StreamReader fileuser;
        public lineUser{
            get{return fileuser;}
            set{fileuser=Value;}
        }
        public foo()
        {
            fileitem = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(desktop, "one.txt"));
            fileuser = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(desktop, "two.txt"));
        }
    }



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int x = 0; x <= 8939500; x++)
        {
            Foo fo=new Foo();
            lineuser = fo.fileuser.ReadLine();                //The error line
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineuser))
            {
                string[] values = lineuser.Split(' ');
                int userid, factoriduser;
                foreach (string value in values)
                {
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @AftabAhmed. but I got the error for " fileuser" not "lineUser" ??

Comment: where is your remaining code ?

Comment: you can create another property for fileuser as well

Comment: I am biginer @AftabAhmed may you detail your answer by a comment,please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of `foo` first and access the `fileuser` through that instance of `foo`

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    // you have to create an instance of foo first:
    var f = new foo();
    for (int x = 0; x <= 8939500; x++) {
        // and access the fileuser through that instance of foo
        lineuser = f.fileuser.ReadLine();                //The error line
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineuser)) {
            string[] values = lineuser.Split(' ');
            int userid, factoriduser;
            foreach (string value in values){
                ........
```